# Error UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library while trying to create a JNI Service

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am trying create a Service that access a JNI shared library, but when it tries to access the lib it returns an exception.

```
 8746 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                  │
 8747 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime: Process: vendor.alvenan.javanativetestservice, PID: 921                                                                │
 8748 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjavanativetestservice_jni.so" not found                     │
 8749 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)                                                                │
 8750 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)                                                                 │
 8751 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)                                                                   │
 8752 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at vendor.alvenan.javanativetestservice.JavaNativeTestServiceImpl.<clinit>(JavaNativeTestServiceImpl.java:14)       │
 8753 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at vendor.alvenan.javanativetestservice.JavaNativeTestService.onCreate(JavaNativeTestService.java:14)               │
 8754 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1277)                                   │
 8755 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6759)                                       │
 8756 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)                                      │
 8757 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133)                                             │
 8758 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                             │
 8759 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)                                                                      │
 8760 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
 8761 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
 8762 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 8763 05-29 05:00:16.259   921   921 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
```

I am using the ARPI13 project:
https://github.com/snappautomotive/firmware_rpi-local_manifests/tree/arpi-13

The JNI lib seems to be in the right place:

```
rpi4:/ # cat vendor/etc/public.libraries.txt
libjavanativetestservice_jni.so
rpi4:/ # ls -l vendor/lib64/libjavanativetestservice_jni.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10952 2023-05-29 15:40 vendor/lib64/libjavanativetestservice_jni.so
```

The full code is on github: https://github.com/alvenan/aosp_bench/tree/main/bench_test_jni

The device makefile has the following setup:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += JavaNativeTestService
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
   vendor/alvenan/aosp_bench/bench_test_jni/public.libraries.txt:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/etc/public.libraries.txt
```

Comment: You could use inotify tools to check where your service is searching for the library.

Comment: Didn't know about this tool, could you explain how to use it to check the service search path?

Comment: This is a standard Linux tool for monitoring file system activity such as file open. Even if the command fails because of a missing file you can see the file path that was tried to open. By default inotify tools are not included in Android but the necessary API is there (can be e.g. used from within an app). On GitHub you will find an older adaption for Android which can be compiled using NDK or you try to use a precompiled version from a Termux repository.

Comment: I could see that the service is searching for the library in /system/lib64 while the .so file is in /vendor/lib64.
I made a copy of the .so to /system/lib64 and it worked, but I think this is not a good practice. So, how could I force the search to /vendor/lib64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `vendor: true` tag from the shared lib Android.bp fixed the problem